# TFS 2010 Build MVC 3 Application Apply Config Transformation

Tags: deployment, msbuild, web-config, tfsbuild

I have an MVC 3 apllication with several config transforms. In TFS build definition I set MSBuild Arguments in Advanced section to **/p:DeployOnBuild=True /t:TransformWebConfig /p:Configuration=Release**. But it has no effect. What is wrong?

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2579229/147211
Also, you can define the configuration on the "configurations to build" node

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found solution [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/tfsbuild/thread/d5c6cc7b-fbb1-4299-a8af-ef602bad8898/). Just need to modify website project file:

```
 <Target Name="AfterBuild">
  <TransformXml Condition="Exists('$(OutDir)\_PublishedWebsites\$(TargetName)')" Source="Web.config" Transform="$(ProjectConfigTransformFileName)" Destination="$(OutDir)\_PublishedWebsites\$(TargetName)\Web.config" />
 </Target>
```